# App Crash using Hot Restart Xamarin Forms on iOS and the ArcGIS Runtime

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, arcgis

Want to check if anyone has had success with the ArcGIS Runtime Xamarin Forms on iOS using Visual Studio  hot restart?

I created a new Xamarin Forms app for iOS in Visual Studio and added the following code in AppDelegate.cs

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
  global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
  LoadApplication(new App());
  Esri.ArcGISRuntime.ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.Initialize();

  return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

The app launches and runs fine without the Initialize method on my iPhone.  It feels like I'm missing a dependency.

This is the error I get with the Initialize method:

```
[0:] An error occurred: 'CoreRT_ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment_setInstallDirectory assembly:<unknown assembly> type:<unknown type> member:(null)'. Callstack: '  at (wrapper managed-to-native) RuntimeCoreNet.GeneratedWrappers.CoreArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.CoreRT_ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment_setInstallDirectory(byte[],intptr&)
  at RuntimeCoreNet.GeneratedWrappers.CoreArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.SetInstallDirectory (System.String installPath) <0x138775060 + 0x00010> in <2a33546a5b934b588629d4e33895c554>:0 
  at Esri.ArcGISRuntime.ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.InitNative () <0x1387748c8 + 0x00004> in <2a33546a5b934b588629d4e33895c554>:0 
  at Esri.ArcGISRuntime.ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment.Initialize () <0x138774538 + 0x00042> in <2a33546a5b934b588629d4e33895c554>:0 
  at App1.iOS.AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching (UIKit.UIApplication app, Foundation.NSDictionary options) [0x00013] in C:\Users\Chris\Documents\OnScene Xplorer\App1\App1.iOS\AppDelegate.cs:33 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:86 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:65 
  at App1.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in C:\Users\Chris\Documents\OnScene Xplorer\App1\App1.iOS\Main.cs:17 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0006a] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/Current/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/RuntimeMethodInfo.cs:395 '
```

Looks like its attempting to make a call into a native method using DllImport per Reflector.

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void CoreRT_ArcGISRuntimeEnvironment_setInstallDirectory([In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] installPath, out IntPtr outErrorHandle);
```

I also tried the sample app from ArcGIS and it also fails the same way once I enable hot restart on it.

More info...

The exception being thrown is EntryPointNotFoundException which means that the native call can't be resolved.

I did some sleuthing on my iPhone and found that runtimecore.dll and runtimecorenet.dll are not being copied to the deployment folder.  They also do not appear in the bin/Debug folder during build.  I believe those 2 dlls are the target of the native calls in Esri.ArcGISRuntime.dll.

So I think I have to figure out how to convince Visual Studio to include those in the iOS build.  I do see them being included in my UWP build.

Any ideas for how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while back Microsoft broke support for native .frameworks in hot restart, and the ArcGIS Runtime relies on these, so unfortunately you'll need a Mac to deploy to a device.